# React Redux Firebase: Error on firebaseConnect - Cannot read property 'ordered' of undefined

Tags: firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

I followed [the example in the documentation](http://react-redux-firebase.com/) under *v2.0.0 > Read Me > Load Data (listeners automatically managed on mount/unmount)* (direct link is not possible).
And replaced the connect call with the firestore specific one shown here](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore.html#examples) in Example 1.

I copied the Todo example exactly in a new component created for testing purposes.

Todo Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { firebaseConnect,firestoreConnect, isLoaded, isEmpty } from 'react-redux-firebase'

const Todos = ({ todos, firebase }) => {
  // Build Todos list if todos exist and are loaded
  const todosList = !isLoaded(todos)
    ? 'Loading'
    : isEmpty(todos)
      ? 'Todo list is empty'
      : Object.keys(todos).map(
          (key, id) => (
            <TodoItem key={key} id={id} todo={todos[key]}/>
          )
        )
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <ul>
        {todosList}
      </ul>
      <input type="text" ref="newTodo" />
      <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

// export default compose(
//   firestoreConnect([
//     'todos' // { path: '/todos' } // object notation
//   ]),
//   connect((state) => ({
//     todos: state.firestore.data.todos,
//     profile: state.firestore.profile // load profile
//   }))
// )(Todos)





export default compose(
 firestoreConnect(['todos']), // or { collection: 'todos' }
 connect((state, props) => ({
   todos: state.firestore.ordered.todos
 }))
)(Todos)
```

The store configuration was configured as shown [here in the docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/#use). The store configuration was adapted to slot into the framework created by `react-boilerplate`.

```
/**
 * Create the store with dynamic reducers
 */

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import { reactReduxFirebase, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { reduxFirestore, firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore'
import firebase from 'firebase/app' 
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/firestore'

import createReducer from './reducers'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
}
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  // useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
  // attachAuthIsReady: true
}

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

  // Initialize Firestore with timeshot settings
  firebase.firestore()
  // firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

  // Create the store with two middlewares
  // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
  // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)]

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    // reactReduxFirebase(config), // enhancing our store with these packages
    // reduxFirestore(config)
  ]

  // If Redux DevTools Extension is installed use it, otherwise use Redux compose
  /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle, indent */
  const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({})
      : compose
  /* eslint-enable */
  const createStoreWithFirebase = compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig), // firebase instance as first argument
    reduxFirestore(firebase),
  )(createStore)

  const store = createStoreWithFirebase(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),

    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
  )

  // Extensions
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run
  store.injectedReducers = {} // Reducer registry
  store.injectedSagas = {} // Saga registry

  // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers))
    })
  }

  return store
}
```

I traced and verified my store configuration exactly to make sure all steps present in the documentation are configured correctly in my configuration.

My `createReducer` funciton is in a seperate file and you can see that I added the `firebaseReducer` and `firebaseReducer` correctly.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable'
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore'
import history from 'utils/history'
import languageProviderReducer from 'containers/LanguageProvider/reducer'

export default function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    firebase: firebaseReducer,
    firestore: firestoreReducer,

    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  })

  // Wrap the root reducer and return a new root reducer with router state
  const mergeWithRouterState = connectRouter(history)
  return mergeWithRouterState(rootReducer)
}
```

My redux store contains the `firestore` and `firebase` and it is injected into the component props.
What does not work is the use of connectFirestore HoC to automatically retrieve and inject a list of documents in to the component.

This is the error message:

```
react-dom.development.js?61bb:20266 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ordered' of undefined
    at Function.eval [as mapToProps] (index.js?d834:49)
    at mapToPropsProxy (wrapMapToProps.js?1817:54)
    at Function.detectFactoryAndVerify (wrapMapToProps.js?1817:63)
    at mapToPropsProxy (wrapMapToProps.js?1817:54)
    at handleFirstCall (selectorFactory.js?805c:37)
    at pureFinalPropsSelector (selectorFactory.js?805c:85)
    at Object.runComponentSelector [as run] (connectAdvanced.js?48b8:43)
    at Connect.initSelector (connectAdvanced.js?48b8:195)
    at new Connect (connectAdvanced.js?48b8:136)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11315)
```

(Snipped from my code which is the example 1 [in documentation](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore.html#examples)):

```
export default compose(
 firestoreConnect(['todos']), // or { collection: 'todos' }
 connect((state, props) => ({
   todos: state.firestore.ordered.todos
 }))
)(Todos)
```

I inspected the `state` variable and it does contain the `firestore` attribute. This attribute contains a number of functions, as expected, but it is missing the query results under "ordered", which is undefined.

I have tried all different ways to use `firestoreconnect` e.g. using a Class-based component, using a query with parameters, etc. and all give the same error.

My Firebase project is configured correct as I am able to create documents inside collections. A `todos` collection for testing purposes is present as well containing 2 documents.

I have come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656082/react-redux-firebase-error-using-firestoreconnect-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a), which mentions the following:

> If you just upgraded to React-Redux v6, it's because react-redux-firebase is not compatible with v6.
>
> See https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/581 for details.

This does not apply to me because I am using `react-redux` version 5. Here are the versions I am using:

```
    "firebase": "^5.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.7.3",
```

I have spent a significant amount of time on this. Like I said, using `firestore` to add new data to collections works fine. It is just this HoC business that is failing no matter how i approach the solution.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Never solved this. I guess it is related to incompatible versions. What I ended up doing is download v4 of react-boilerplate and set up v3 react-redux-firebase which uses the Context API as opposed to store enhancers. Now works very well.